# WinRT DataBinding with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties

In my ViewModel I've defined following `ObservableCollection`.

```
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ChartSerie> _seriesData = new ObservableCollection<ChartSerie>();
    public ObservableCollection<ChartSerie> SeriesData
    {
        get { return _seriesData; }
    }
```

On my Page I bind this collection.

```
ItemSource="{Binding SeriesData}"
```

ItemSource is a DependencyProperty in my control.

```
public object ItemSource
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(object), typeof(MultipleColumnChart), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemSourceChanged));
```

The control inherits from Grid. I've defined `OnItemSourceChanged` as following.

```
private static void OnItemSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    var chart = d as MultipleDoubleColumnChart;
    foreach (var serie in (IList)chart.ItemSource)
    {
        var child = new ColumnChart();
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

When the Page and ViewModel are created the SeriesData collection is empty and the first and only call to `OnItemSourceChanged` does nothing (as expected). After a certain button click on the page the data were loaded and new ChartSerie object were created and added to `SeriesData`.

Although `SeriesData` is an `ObservableCollection` the `OnItemSourceChanged` Method is not called anymore.

What is/went wrong and what do I need to change that OnItemSourceChanged will be called?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` does not force a call to `OnItemSourceChanged`. In the standard `ItemsControl`, it fires `OnItemsChanged`. What you have to do is cast the `ItemSource` as an `INotifyCollectionChanged` (when the property is being set), then (if it's not null) add an event handler to `CollectionChanged`. This will fire when the data changes.

Comment: Ok, so I have this in OnItemSourceChanged:
`var source = (System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged)chart.ItemSource;
source.CollectionChanged += Source_CollectionChanged;`

`Source_CollectionChanged` is static how can I access non static methods like I have in 'OnItemSourceChange' Parameter -> `DependencyObject d`?

Comment: Generally, I don't set `CollectionChanged` in `OnItemSourceChanged`; I set it in the setter method of `ItemSource`. This way, `Source_CollectionChanged` isn't `static`. If you still want to use it as is, you can case the `sender` parameter that the method receives, similar to how you cast `d as MultipleDoubleColumnChart`.